# Vectorized computation of numpys tensor dot

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, tensordot

I have two vectors containing tensors of shape `(3,3)` and shape `(3,3,3,3)` respectively. The vectors have the same length, I am computing the element-wise tensor dot of these two vectors . For example, want to vectorise the following computation to improve performance:

```
a = np.arange(9.).reshape(3,3)
b = np.arange(81.).reshape(3,3,3,3)
c = np.tensordot(a,b)

a_vec = np.asanyarray([a,a])
b_vec = np.asanyarray([b,b])    
c_vec = np.empty(a_vec.shape)

for i in range(c_vec.shape[0]):
    c_vec[i, :, :] = np.tensordot(a_vec[i,:,:], b_vec[i,:,:,:,:])

print(np.allclose(c_vec[0], c))
# True
```

I thought about using [numpy.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) but can't figure out the correct subscripts. I have tried a lot of different approaches but failed so far on all of them:

```
# I am trying something like this
c_vec = np.einsum("ijk, ilmno -> ijo", a_vec, b_vec)

print(np.allclose(c_vec[0], c))
# False
```

But this does not reproduce the iterative computation I want above. If this can't be done using einsum or there is a more performant way to do this, I am open for any kind of solutions.

Comment: what's the point of doubling the input arrays? This part: `a_vec = np.asanyarray([a,a])`

Comment: @Divakar yes exactly, I am trying to vectorise the loop. I have *a lot* of tensors and hope to speed it up this way.

Comment: @Marat There is no point really, I am just using this as a sanity check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vectorized way with [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) would be -

```
c_vec = np.einsum('ijk,ijklm->ilm',a_vec,b_vec)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tensor_dot` has an `axes` argument you can use too:

```
c_vec = np.tensordot(a_vec, b_vec, axes=([1, 2], [1, 2]))
```